# CXF No Databinding client

Tags: xml, cxf

I am trying to figure out how to use cxf to send a client request to a web client without databinding. The use case I have is that everything bar the envelope i.e. the payload XML, is being sent to me and I have to send validate that xml as well as send it to the web service. [Somebody else will generate the xml, I have no input on that, and they want me to send it]. To date I have been using JAXB but in this case I will already have the desired XML.

Many thanks,
Regards.

Comment: The cxf sample project jaxws_dispatch_provider should point the way.